# Facing zlib not available error while installing Ansible offline Installation with Python and PIP in RHEL 7

Tags: python, pip, ansible, offline

Facing zlib not available error while installing Ansible offline Installation with Python and PIP
although Python is install properly but PIP installation occurs zlib not available error which is mentioned below:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "get-pip.py", line 22711, in <module>
       main()
        File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
          bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
           File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
         from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
         zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Comment: Well, zlib not available. You need to install it. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+zipimport.ZipImportError%3A+can%27t+decompress+data%3B+zlib+not+available

Comment: OS shows zlib is already installed but while installing error occurs zlib not available

Comment: is there any appropriate link available of ansible offline installation with its all dependencies?

Comment: "*OS shows zlib is already installed*" It could be Python's module `zlib` is not linked with the system library.

Comment: can you tell me how to link zlib with the system library?